# restart the rsession using R code

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there any R code to restart the rsession? I am usually doing this by pressing `cntrl+shift+0`. 
But now want to do this in my code. how can i do this?

Comment: The correct way is to do:
invisible(.rs.restartR())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are actually trying to accomplish, you may simply want something like

```
  rm(list=ls())
```

Note: be careful this code actually delete your entire work/variable/data

Comment: For the record, this is quite different from restarting an R session. Following this answer, packages are not unloaded, variables whose names start with `.` are not deleted, any mutable state of packages is not reset, and any startup scripts are not rerun.